# Integral involving $\cosh$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

How can I calculate the following integral using Mathematica?
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\left(1+x^2\right) \operatorname{ch} \frac{\pi x}{2}} = 2 \ln 2$$

I tried:

```
int1 = Assuming[Element[x, Reals], 
  Integrate[
   FullSimplify[1/((1 + x^2)*Cosh[(Pi*x)/2])], {x, -Infinity, 
    Infinity}, PrincipalValue -> True]]

int2 = Integrate[
  1/((1 + x^2)*Cosh[(Pi*x)/2]), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> Element[x, Reals], GenerateConditions -> False]

int3 = Integrate`InverseIntegrate[
 1/((1 + x^2)*Cosh[(Pi*x)/2]), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> Element[x, Reals]]
```

I can calculate it using the residue theorem, but this belongs to mathematics. Is it possible to directly solve this integral with Mathematica without using the residue theorem?

Comment: Isn't `NIntegrate[1/((1 + x^2)*Cosh[(Pi*x)/2]), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]` enough?

Comment: @user64494 I want to get an analytical solution `Log[4]`.

Comment: What for? Isn't it art for art's sake?

Comment: @user64494  As you said, we use numerical integration to do integrals. Why do we still need to learn complex analysis and calculus? Can we just learn numerical methods? Because many people need to derive formulas, such as those majoring in physics. The advantage of mma is that it is good at symbolic computation, so I don't need to say more about it.

Comment: @lotus2019: I prefer arguments, not questions instead of.

Comment: This is Gradshtein & Ruezhik, 3.522.8. They refer to Bierens de Hanaan D. Nouvelles tables.... Amsterdam, 1867.

Comment: Roman's answer prompted this reflection: If we're going to use math to do math, why not simply use the residue theorem? It can be done easily in Mma. -- This question is a bit of a strange question, of the sort, "I want to do it in this way which doesn't work? How do I that? I know I can use math to do it another way, but I don't want to do that." So I wonder which alternatives will be acceptable...

Comment: @Michael E2 Yes, what you said is actually the meaning of using mma. In many cases, of course, we can use manual calculation to derive formulas, or we can use mma to assist with manual calculation, such as using the residue theorem in mma. However, if we focus more on the results of derivation rather than the process, if there is faster mma code, it will certainly better meet our requirements.

Comment: @Michael E2 For example, `f[x_] :=Sin[x]/(x*(x^2 - 1))`, `Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, Infinity}]` cannot obtain the result, and using the residue theorem is certainly feasible. However, `FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, Infinity}, PrincipalValue -> True]]]`, the result can be obtained immediately. When I asked this question, I was not sure if there was any faster code for the integration in this question.

Comment: @ydd: Even $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac 1 {1+x^2}$  converges and $\cosh(\pi x/2) \ge 1$ for real values of $x$.

Comment: Since when `Cosh` is denoted as $ch$?

Comment: @yarchik, this is a [common notation](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_functions), especially in Europe, and also the original notation of Riccati and Lambert.

Comment: @Domen I see, I didn't know that. I personally confused the ch notation with cn, which is the Jacobi elliptic function and which is closely related $\mathrm{cn}(u,0)=\cos(u)$ and $\mathrm{cn}(u,1)=\mathrm{sech}(u)$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use an [integral representation](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Sech/07/01/01/) of $\text{sech}(z)=1/\text{cosh}(z)$:

```
Assuming[Element[x, Reals],
  2/π Integrate[t^(I x)/(t^2 + 1), {t, 0, ∞}]]

(*    Sech[π x/2]    *)
```

The integral can thus be written as a double integral. With [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) we can flip the integration order:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)\text{cosh}\frac{\pi x}{2}}
=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\int_0^{\infty}dt\frac{2t^{i x}}{\pi(1+x^2)(1+t^2)}\\
=\int_0^{\infty}dt\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\frac{2t^{i x}}{\pi(1+x^2)(1+t^2)}\\
=\int_0^{\infty}dt\frac{2e^{-|\ln t|}}{1+t^2}
=2\ln2.
$$

Using Mathematica:

```
Integrate[2/π t^(I x)/((1 + t^2) (1 + x^2)), {x, -∞, ∞}, {t, 0, ∞}]
(*    Integrate[Sech[π*x/2]/(1 + x^2), {x, -∞, ∞}]    *)

Integrate[2/π t^(I x)/((1 + t^2) (1 + x^2)), {t, 0, ∞}, {x, -∞, ∞}]
(*    Log[4]    *)
```

Comment: You mimic with MMA the math calculation done by hand.

Comment: @user64494 yes that’s how tools work.

Answer (score 4):

The `Log[2]` comes from Dirichlet eta function at `1`.
We have partial fraction expansion for hyperbolic secant:

```
Sech[(π x)/2]==4/π Sum[(((2 n-1)/((2 n-1)^2+x^2)) (-1)^(n+1)),{n,1,∞}]
1/(x^2+1) Sech[(π x)/2]==Sum[(4/π 1/(x^2+1) ((2 n-1)/((2 n-1)^2+x^2)) (-1)^(n+1)),{n,1,∞}]

(* True *)
(* True *)
```

$$\text{sech}\left(\frac{\pi  x}{2}\right)=\frac{4}{\pi}\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(2 n-1) (-1)^{n+1}}{(2 n-1)^2+x^2}$$

$$\frac{1}{x^2+1}\text{sech}\left(\frac{\pi  x}{2}\right)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{4}{\pi}\frac{1}{\left(x^2+1\right)}\frac{(2 n-1) (-1)^{n+1}}{(2 n-1)^2+x^2}$$

We integrate inside of the sum which will output explicit function.

```
(exp=Integrate[
  4/π 1/(x^2 + 1) ((2 n - 1)/((2 n - 1)^2 + x^2)) (-1)^(n + 1), 
  x]) == ((-1)^(
  1 + n) (-1 + 2 n) ((-1 + 2 n) ArcTan[x] + ArcTan[x/(1 - 2 n)]))/(
 n (1 - 3 n + 2 n^2) π)

(* True *)
```

$$exp=\int \frac{4}{\pi}\frac{1}{\left(x^2+1\right)}\frac{(2 n-1) (-1)^{n+1}}{(2 n-1)^2+x^2} \, dx=\frac{(-1)^{n+1} (2 n-1) \left(\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{1-2 n}\right)+(2 n-1) \tan ^{-1}(x)\right)}{\pi  n \left(2 n^2-3 n+1\right)}$$

We compute limit of `exp` at `x=∞` and `x=-∞` and subtract them.

```
Limit[exp, x -> ∞], 
  Assumptions -> n \[Element] PositiveIntegers] == -((-1)^n/n)
Limit[exp, x -> -∞, 
  Assumptions -> n \[Element] PositiveIntegers] == (-1)^n/n

(* True *)
(* True *)
```

$$lim1-lim2=-2 \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$$

$$int=-2 \sum _{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}=2 \sum _{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}=2 \eta (1)=2 \ln 2$$

Comment: It is not so simple. The series `Sum[(((2 n-1)/((2 n-1)^2+x^2)) (-1)^(n+1)),{n,1,∞}]` converges only conditionally: `SumConvergence[((2 n - 1)/((2 n - 1)^2 + x^2)) , n, 
 Assumptions -> x >= 0]` produces `False`. Therefore,  the change of order of the integration and summation is built on the sand.

Comment: You have missing `(-1)^n` in your  in your `SumConvergence`, the sum with it converges. It does not matter whether conditionally or not because I did not change order of summation of the sum.

Comment: I consider the absolute convergence of the series `Sum[(((2 n-1)/((2 n-1)^2+x^2)) (-1)^(n+1)),{n,1,∞}]` as  written in my comment.  The absolute convergence implies the possibility of the replacing of  the summation and integration, but the absolute convergence is false. Hope I am clear.

Comment: I think your calculations can be justified, but this needs some arguments. In any case, +1 from me.

Comment: I agree with @user64494 that you make some adventurous assumptions about the applicability of Fubini’s theorem here.

Comment: @user64494: Would be great if you can provide example when changing order of conditional summation and integration fails.

Comment: @azerbajdzan: For example, see Gelbaum&Olmsted,  Counterexamples in analysis, Chap. 7, Par. 6 to this end. More exactly, the uniform convergence is essential here.

Comment: @Roman: azerbajdzan does not apply Fubini's theorem at all, but interchanges the order of the integration an summation.

Comment: @user64494: If the sum is convergent (unconditionally or not) for all `x` in the range between lower and upper limit of the integral then the order of the sum and integral can be changed. In my case the sum is (conditionally) convergent for all real `x` including `-∞` and `∞` and we are integrating from `-∞` to`∞` therefore I can change the order.

Comment: @azerbajdzan:  Did you look in Gelbaum&Olmsted, Counterexamples in analysis, Chap. 7, Par. 6 before having submitted that?

Comment: @user64494: On the page 79 I can doubt that $\underset{n\to \infty }{\text{lim}}f_n(x)=0$ as the author is claiming. In fact the function at `x=0` and `n->∞` take on every value between `0` and `∞`.

Comment: @user64494: In fact the function `f_n(x)` becomes a diract delta function for `n->∞` and integral of dirac delta function from `0` to `∞` is `1/2` ... i.e. I got to same result in both cases whether order of computation was integration-summation or summation-integration.  So it is not a good example.

Comment: @azerbajdzan Are you saying  Gelbaum & Olmsted book is wrong?

Comment: No, I am saying that this particular example on page 79 is wrong/not good/inappropriate/unsuitable, whatever you call it. Every book has some mistakes or inaccuracies, but this does not mean the book overall is wrong.

Comment: @azerbajdzan As n goes to infinity the composite function becomes a constant function y = 0. Because only third condition remains. But is it really relevant to this, it is "sequence of functions", functional analysis? That is VERY complicated. What they're talking about is that the functions change and the sequence limit of the change of those functions is indeed y = 0.

Comment: @Валерий Заподовников: Did you visualize the function f_n(x) for yourself? It has the shape of isosceles triangle that becomes higher and narrower for increasing `n`. For `n->∞` it becomes Dirac delta function. It is constant only for `x>0` but not at `x=0`. So no, no, for `n->∞` and at `x=0` all three conditions remain not just the third one. I would accept answer that for `n->∞` the limit has no sense or does not exist but never the author claim that `f_∞(x)=0` just to suit the author needs without any evidence.

Comment: @user64494 This is not function series. This is sequence of functions, I do not know all rules for those, googling shows Pointwise Convergence, Uniform Convergence, criterions for those. I did not study that, azerbajdzan.

Answer (score 0):

I propose the following way: Let us represent the `Cosh[(Pi*x)/2]->(Exp[(Pi*x)/2]+Exp[-(Pi*x)/2])/2` as a sum of the exponents. Then the whole integral, `int`, can be represented as a sum of two terms:

```
int=int1+int2;
```

Here int1 only contains the converging parts of the integrals:

```
int1 = 1/
  2 (Inactive[Integrate][Exp[\[Pi]*x/2]/(
     1 + x^2), {x, -\[Infinity], 0}] + 
    Inactive[Integrate][Exp[-\[Pi]*x/2]/(
     1 + x^2), {x, 0, \[Infinity]}])
```

[image]

```
int1 // Activate // FullSimplify

(*  CosIntegral[\[Pi]/2]  *)
```

int2 contains all the rest:

```
int2 =1/2 ( Inactive[Integrate][Exp[\[Pi]*x/2]/(
   1 + x^2), {x, 0, \[Infinity]}] + 
  Inactive[Integrate][Exp[-\[Pi]*x/2]/(1 + x^2), {x, -\[Infinity], 0}])
```

[image]

Let us change variables in the first of these two integrals:

```
    int2 = 1/
   2 (IntegrateChangeVariables[
      Inactive[Integrate][Exp[\[Pi]*x/2]/(
       1 + x^2), {x, 0, \[Infinity]}], t, t == -x] + 
     Inactive[Integrate][Exp[-\[Pi]*x/2]/(
      1 + x^2), {x, -\[Infinity], 0}]) /. t -> x
```

[image]

Now everything is clear, but it is a pleasure to go to the end with the Mma tools. Let us use the following rule to fuse the inactive integrals:

```
rule = Inactive[Integrate][g1__, {x, a_, b_}] + 
    Inactive[Integrate][g2__, {x, a_, b_}] :> 
   Inactive[Integrate][Simplify[g1 + g2], {x, a, b}];
```

and now:

```
int2 /. rule // Activate

(*  0  *)
```

The result is `CosIntegral[\[Pi]/2]`. Why is it not 2ln2, I do not know. However,

```
NIntegrate[1/((1 + x^2)*Cosh[(Pi*x)/2]), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]

(*  1.38629 *)
```

while

```
CosIntegral[\[Pi]/2] // N

(* 0.472001  *)
```

Something is evidently wrong in my solution.

Comment: The $\cosh(\pi x/2)$ is in the denominator but you expanded it in the numerator.